# conditional constraints for django model

Tags: python, django, model

I have database model like this

```
ActionType = (
    (1,"PostBack"),
    (2,"Uri"),
)

class RichMenu(BaseModel):
    key = m.CharField(max_length=64,unique=True)
    action_type = m.IntegerField(choices=ActionType,default=1)
    url = m.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    name = m.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
```

Now I would like to make constraint like this,

- When `action_type` is 1, `url` should be null and `name` should not be null
- When `action_type` is 2, `name` should be null and `url` should not be null

Is it possible to make conditional constraints for this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite method save() to valid field before save it to database

```
ActionType = (
    (1,"PostBack"),
    (2,"Uri"),
)

class RichMenu(BaseModel):
    key = m.CharField(max_length=64,unique=True)
    action_type = m.IntegerField(choices=ActionType,default=1)
    url = m.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    name = m.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.action_type == 1:
            if self.url is not None and self.name is None:
                raise Exception("INVALID URL AND NAME")
        elif self.action_type == 2:
            if self.url is None and self.name is not None:
                raise Exception("INVALID URL AND NAME")
        super(RichMenu, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This will break easily when updating with `QuerySet.update`, which does not call the `save` method.

Comment: @blhsing  thanks for this case. So, I think it would be move the rule valid to a private fuction valid and call it in method save and update

Answer (score 1):

Django 2.2 introduced [CheckConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint)

```
class RichMenu(m.Model):
    key = m.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    action_type = m.IntegerField(choices=ActionType, default=1)
    url = m.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    name = m.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check=(
                    Q(
                        action_type=1,
                        url__isnull=True,
                        name__isnull=False,
                    )
                    | Q(
                        action_type=2,
                        url__isnull=False,
                        name__isnull=True,
                    )
                ),
                name='url_or_name_not_null_based_on_action_type_check',
            ),
        ]
```